# What user.agent property value should i use in gwt.xml for FF21?

Tags: gwt, compilation, gwt-dev-mode

I want to reduce the time it takes in devmode  to turn my gwt app into javascript. For that i'm thinking of limiting the user.agent values to the one corresponding to FF21. gecko1_8 is suggested to be for FF3. And gecko1_9 does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one firefox user agent and is `gecko1_8`. It targets the gecko engine 1.8 and onwards, hence FF >= 1.5 according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29#Usage).

Have a look at [here](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml) to find all the available user agents you can use.

Comment: i have a gwt.xml that states:  where value = "ie6/opera/gecko1_8/safari/gecko" , "gecko1_8" is FireFox 3

Comment: `gecko1_8` roughly means "all FFs starting from gecko 1.8 engine". Of course FF3 is included, but it is not specifically for it. Have a look at [here](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1081801).